# Update "overdue" formulas in Power Query

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I have several files where I have several tasks. Each task has a "to be completed" date attached to it and a formula that calculates whether the task is "overdue" or "not yet due".

To generate a complete overview, I've created one Masterfile and used Power Query to link all these individual files. This works properly, however one issue I can't resolve which is the following:

The Power Query does not refresh the "overdue/not due" formula, when I am refreshing the Query. As such the Masterfile states that tasks that were "not due" at the time I saved the original file, are still not due, although they are in fact "overdue".. I think the Power Query read the original files without updating the formula's.. Is there anyway to resolve this?

Comment: Do you still have the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is no *easy* way to resolve this. Three possible options :

1. If you want to accomplish this just from within your Masterfile, you can create a VBA script in your Masterfile that opens and closes all linked workbooks (see more info [here](http://access-excel.tips/excel-vba-refresh-closed-workbook/)). Please note that you must have access to these files (can be tricky if these are on a network drive or in the cloud);
2. You also can just manually open and close the individual files before you open the Masterfile (or before you refresh the data);
3. Change your approach/formulas, and use the individual files as pure data files, without any formula's that need refreshing, and do all calculations in the Masterfile.

My personal preference/recommendation would be 3), as I have some bad experiences from working with linked workbooks. My own approach if it is really necessary to exchange data between Excel files, is to create a Transfer tab/worksheet in the source workbook where you put all data that the other workbook needs, and create a Source tab/worksheet in the other workbook, and I copy/paste-as-values from one to the other, in particular when both workbooks are "in development". Once workbooks are stable (but does that ever happens?), you still can link the Target>Source worksheets (but auditing errors is just easier instead of having links all over your workbooks).